# Test disk write speed on existing partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, benchmarking

I want to benchmark write speeds on a disk in an existing server setup. I suspect there is a problem with the write perf of the controller. Benchmarks I have tried (SiSoft Sandra, HDTune)  report that write testing cannot be performed since the disk has partitions.

How can I do a write speed benchmark for disk that isn't empty? I don't mind if it is a rudimentary test, but something a bit better than me using a stopwatch and copying a file has to be possible?

Comment: You might also want to check the S.M.A.R.T. status of your drive, type "wmic diskdrive get status, caption, description" in cmd to list all disks and their status.

Answer (score 2):

I see that your request is for a Windows System, use the following commands :

> winsat disk -drive "drive letter"

Answer (score 0):

There's so many [disk speed utilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=diskspeed) that you have not tried yet.
Try [RoadKil](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P13/) or [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) for Windows, or [BlackMagic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) for Mac.

Comment: I like the BlackMagic one for Mac OS a ton. On Linux machines, I combine the 'time' command with a call to 'dd'. That being said, 'dd' should be used with extreme care.